# Session problem in Localhost (wamp2)

Tags: php, session, localhost

I am using wamp 2 for accessing one of my project on localhost, initially i had a problem of maintaining the session in my localhost which i resolved by enabling session.auto_start and providing the domain name with period (.) in it as "**127.0.0.1**",

But now the problem is whenever I switch to another page I do not get anything on the page page is complete white. And when I reset the session.auto_start to 0 then everything comes to normal but then session is not maintained... so how can i do this?

Could anyone help me to resolve this problem..???

Comment: Check if your session save path is defined properly .

Comment: Hello Russell, its is set as "c:/wamp/tmp".. Is it ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try turning on php errors and set error reporting to E_ALL

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

I's most likely session related but the error messages will help pinpoint the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you put `session_start()` on top of the page(s) where you are using the session functions.

Comment: Sarfaraz I am using osCommerce 2.0 I cannot do this as I dont know how many pages are there where I have to do this, tell me something ekse